# "ImportError: No module named requests" In burp suite extension

Tags: python, burp, suite

I am using burp suite extension to intercept https requests and responses and trying to import requests module to do so but when adding the extension, burp raises error

> "ImportError: No module named requests"

, but the module is installing and running in cmd.

what should I do ?

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no :( but i found another way to do burp work. Try MINTMPROXY, this should solve the problem

Comment: I found it. I just had to set the in the Extension > Options tab the "Folder for loading modules"
Anyway there's also another way, using burp helpers to create requests and submit them using the internal engine, completely avoiding using requests.

Comment: If you want some examples on how to do this, checkout the extension I'm writing https://github.com/DrRek/Burp-Auto-Fuzz
Basically, i want to use this to quickly fuzz with some simple payloads in every endpoint to make sure there are no easily spotted vulnerabilities